# DSC-H300/DSC-H400 supported by Remote API beta

Tags: camera, sony

I know the page containing the supported devices for the Camera Remote API Beta. But I wonder if maybe it is possible to use the Remote API Beta with the DSC-H300/DSC-H400 as well, even though they are not declared as supporting the API.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about camera hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cameras DSC-H300 & DSC-H400 do not support Camera Remote API beta.
Both DSC-HX60 & DSC-HX400 long zoom cameras support the Remote API.

More info:
https://developer.sony.com/devices/cameras/

Best Regards, Prem, Developer World